# Is it possible to do Controller specific routing in MVC5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I want all my actions in a single controller to point to a specific View folder. I am going to have many AnalyticControllers that Inherit from a parent controller. The goal is to have individual routing for the child controller to the parent controllers view folder.

I have

```
public class HomeController : Controller 
{         
       //Controller stuff
}

public class HomeAnalyticsController : HomeController 
{
    //All my actions need to point to /Home/viewInQuestion.cshtml

}
```

I want all the actions called in the HomeAnalyticsController to point to /Home/(view here)

I would like to avoid pathing all of my returns if possible.

```
public ActionResult MyAction()
{  
   return View("../Home/MyAction");
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify your question please? "I want all my actions in a single controller to point to a specific View folder." <-- This is out-of-the-box behaviour. All actions from the HomeController point to Views in the Home subfolder under the Views folder.

Comment: You can put them in Shared folder or you subclass RazorViewEngine (take a look at its source code to see how) and then change the view paths.

Comment: I want to do this for many controllers. I was hoping to only do it on a controller by controller basis. I was hoping not to have to change the ViewEngine for the entire app

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why do you want all actions to go to one view?

Comment: You might be able to use an action filter for this, but really, if you're currently using the default RazorViewEngine it would not be hard to override that to do what you want: http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/NcJP200113-Custom-Razor-View-Engine-for-C